# Firebase Storage Offline Capability

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

So I want to find the way to load a file(.txt and .html) in the app from Firebase Storage in offline mode except for the first time. This means a user will load the data for the first time in online mode and can access that data another time with offline mode. So is there any method to do it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This means a user will load the data for the first time in online mode and can access that data another time with offline mode. So is there any method to do it?

For sure, there is. There is a library called [Glide for Android](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), that can help you achieve what you want:

> Glide is a fast and efficient open-source media management and image loading framework for Android that wraps media decoding, memory and **disk caching**, and resource pooling into a simple and easy-to-use interface.

This means that you can load an image once and then read it from the cache.

Comment: It is only for images, right? I want load a .txt and .html files and display the text to users

Comment: In that case, you should consider saving that `.txt` file on the local disk.

Comment: Yeah, I feel that's the only option left.